# Multiple HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have some trouble with TreeView in WPF.
I have got three collection which contains each other.
So, i have got a Group type, in it there is a MasterActions ObservableCollection.
In MasterAction there is a SlaveActions ObservableCollection.
Group, MasterAction and SlaveAction classes have a Description property.
I would like to bind them to a TreeView.
I tried HierarchicalDataTemplate construction, but it is not working.

### There is the Xaml code:

```
<TreeView x:Name="TreeViewResult" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="10,10,10,10" >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding MasterActions}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SlaveActions}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

### Codebehind:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Group group1 = new Group("group1_description");
MasterAction masterAction11 = new MasterAction("masterAction11");
SlaveAction slaveAction111 = new SlaveAction("slaveAction111");
SlaveAction slaveAction112 = new SlaveAction("slaveAction112");
MasterAction masterAction12 = new MasterAction("masterAction12");
MasterAction masterAction13 = new MasterAction("masterAction13");
SlaveAction slaveAction131 = new SlaveAction("slaveAction131");
handler.Add(group1);
handler.Add(masterAction11);
handler.Add(slaveAction111);
handler.Add(slaveAction112);
handler.Add(masterAction12);
handler.Add(masterAction13);
handler.Add(slaveAction131);
Group group2 = new Group("group2_description");
MasterAction masterAction21 = new MasterAction("masterAction21");
MasterAction masterAction22 = new MasterAction("masterAction22");
SlaveAction slaveAction221 = new SlaveAction("slaveAction221");
SlaveAction slaveAction222 = new SlaveAction("slaveAction222");
SlaveAction slaveAction223 = new SlaveAction("slaveAction223");
SlaveAction slaveAction224 = new SlaveAction("slaveAction224");
handler.Add(group2);
handler.Add(masterAction21);
handler.Add(masterAction22);
handler.Add(slaveAction221);
handler.Add(slaveAction222);
handler.Add(slaveAction224);
TreeViewResult.ItemsSource = handler.Groups;
```

Handler.Add() is an overloaded method. It manages all of three parameter to construct tree.

```
group1_description
    masterAction11
        slaveAction111
        slaveAction112
    masterAction12
    masterAction13
        slaveAction131
group2_description
    masterAction21
    masterAction22
        slaveAction221
        slaveAction222
        slaveAction223
        slaveAction224
```

When i run the code, it produces the next:

### [image]

How can i reach to appear all MasterActions and SlaveActions description under the right node?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems like your setting your ItemsSource via Binding to DataContext 

ItemsSource="{Binding}"  and then in code TRVRes.ItemsSource = groups.

so which is it you can't do both

further more where exactly do you add all the MasterAction types as a to a collection which is defined under type "Group" as a Property called "MasterActions" as specified in your binding


Group -> MasterActions -> SalveActions
and in your ItemsSource is indeed a Collection of Group and not just  you VM or Code behind if your code behind is also your DataContext you need to set it to itself this.DataContext = this;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if you try to go one level too deep with your `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. You set `ItemsSource` in your code to `Groups`

```
TreeViewResult.ItemsSource = handler.Groups;
```

and it actually does not matter how you set it (in code or via binding) more important is that top level item is a `Group` and you bind top level `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource` to `Groups`. Instead of that move everything one level up and bind top level `ItemsSource` to `MasterActions`, next level to `SlaveActions` and lowest level can then be simple `DataTemplate` that would display `Description` without child nodes

```xml
<TreeView 
    x:Name="TreeViewResult" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    Margin="10,10,10,10" >
    <!-- top node will be a Group -->
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding MasterActions}">
            <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
            <!-- child node will be a MasterAction -->
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SlaveActions}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                    <!-- leaf will be a SlaveAction -->
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

also, not related to your problem, but since you display single `TextBlock` you don't need `StackPanel`

Comment: he did several things wrong i don't have time to write an answer look at my comment above.

Comment: yes and my answer should cover these issues and code above should work

Comment: Hi, i will answer tomorrow. Thanks for your corrections.